# Next.js - best way to serve static JS from a node module's "dist" folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, tesseract

I'm working with an application that uses Tesseract (OCR) to read text from images.

I would like to take some JS files from node_modules/tesseract.js/dist and make them downloadable in the browser.

I know I can just copy the files to ./public and next.js will serve it statically from there, but then if I update my version of Tesseract, I may need to update those files as well. So maintenance becomes a problem.

My 1st thought is to customize my webpack config to copy the files from node_modules/tesseract.js/dist to ./public/tesseract (or something like that). That would make sure the files get re-copied if I update Tesseract. But I'm not particularly savvy with webpack and haven't figured out how to do that yet.

My 2nd thought was to "proxy" the retrieval of the JS file's content and just make the content available as a "page" in next.js (but this seems super hacktastic).

I feel like this is something that shouldn't be so complicated ... but I've not been able to figure it out myself yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup agreed, updating your server to serve a `node_modules` path sounds a bit dangerous.

I personally would just copy over these files with webpack like you mentioned.

Here are the docs on Next.js on [how to set up a custom webpack config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config).

`next.config.js`

```js
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    // append the CopyPlugin to copy the file to your public dir
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: "node_modules/tesseract.js/dist", to: "public/" },
        ],
      }),
    )

    // Important: return the modified config
    return config
  }
};
```

I purposefully didn't include the `public/tesseract` path, I'm not sure if the `CopyPlugin` will automatically generate missing directories if they don't exist at build time.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response and the webpack guidance! I'll give that a shot and see how it pans out.

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. It took me some time (and some learning) to understand what was happening, but your suggestion worked as advertised.

Comment: Happy to help @ron :)

Comment: on Window use it ```{ from: "node_modules/some-lib/dist/js", to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'some-lib', 'js')}```

Comment: This approach seems to copy the dependencies to your `public/` directory, which mixes up dependencies with the project-specific version-controlled files in `public/`.

Comment: If I have two .js files named `worker.js` from different libraries, how do I distinguish between them?