# How can I include files from node_modules in my Next.js build so that they can be dynamically fetched?

Tags: next.js, node-modules, fetch-api

My goal is to use [the `pyodide` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pyodide) in a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project. Pyodide works like this:

```js
import * as pyodideModule from "pyodide";
// ...
const pyodide = await pyodideModule.loadPyodide({
  indexURL: "/pyodide-data",
});
```

The Pyodide client uses the `indexURL` to essentially do this:

```js
fetch(indexURL + "/pyodide.asm.data")
fetch(indexURL + "/repodata.json")
fetch(indexURL + "/pyodide.asm.wasm")
fetch(indexURL + "/pyodide_py.tar")
fetch(indexURL + "/pyodide.asm.js")
```

These files are supplied in the `pyodide` npm package:

```
$ find node_modules/pyodide/py*
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.asm.data
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.asm.js
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.asm.wasm
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.d.ts
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.js
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.js.map
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.mjs
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide.mjs.map
node_modules/pyodide/pyodide_py.tar
```

So I need to make those files part of my Next.js build.

I could do the dumb thing of manually copying the files into my `public/` directory, but this means I need to ensure the versions are the same, and it pollutes my version control. I would much rather the build system do this for me.

I found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887731/next-js-best-way-to-serve-static-js-from-a-node-modules-dist-folder) which uses `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy the files into my `public/` directory, but this still pollutes my version controlled project-specific files in `public/`.

I've also tried copying to `.next/static/pyodide-data` and then telling Pyodide to load its files from the base URL `"/_next/static/pyodide-data"`. This works, but feels very hacky - I'm using the private `_next` namespace.

**What's the official, non-hacky Next.js way to make `node_modules` files available for dynamic `fetch`ing from the client?**

Comment: I suspect your approach may work, but also wanted to note that `<Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.23.3/full/pyodide.js" />` via https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts and `window.loadPyodide()` seemed to work okay too.